# Unit Test OData in Web API Using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I'm trying to unit test a GET method in a `Web API` controller method that takes an `ODataQueryOptions` parameter.  I need to verify the `OData` filter result and I don't know how to do the assertion.  What do I assert on? Am I testing this properly?

I am using this as inspiration: [Web API, OData, $inlinecount and testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790695/web-api-odata-inlinecount-and-testing?rq=1)

*EDIT*:  Do I need to Assert this for a valid test?  This is what's returned from my `TryGetContentValue` call.  If so, how do I do it?

```
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CSR.Service.Models.CSRRole].Where($it => ($it.RoleName == value(System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.LinqParameterContainer+TypedLinqParameterContainer`1[System.String]).TypedProperty))}
```

UNIT TEST

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetTestWithOData()
        {
            // Arrange
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:21584/api/test?$filter=RoleName%20eq%20'User'");
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<CSRRole>("CSRRoles");
            var opts = new ODataQueryOptions<CSRRole>(new ODataQueryContext(modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(CSRRole)), request);
            var uowMock = new Mock<ICSRUnitOfWork>();
            uowMock.SetupGet(i => i.TestRepository).Returns(new Mock<IGenericRepository<CSRRole, CSRContext>>().Object);
            var controller = new TestController(uowMock.Object);
            controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            controller.Request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration());

            // Act
            var result = controller.Get(opts);

            //Assert
            IQueryable<CSRRole> roles;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);                
            // **** I don't think this is a good test ****
            Assert.IsTrue(result.TryGetContentValue<IQueryable<CSRRole>>(out roles));
        }
```

CONTROLLER METHOD

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions<CSRRole> options)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            if (options == null)
            {
                return response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var result = options.ApplyTo(_csrUnitOfWork.TestRepository.Get());

            if (result == null)
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
                response.Content.Headers.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300));
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Did you get it to work in some way?

Comment: @Rikard...I never did and gave up on it.  If you have a solution, please post an answer.

Comment: I manage to test the query if I use QueryOptions.ApplyTo. Shoud that be okay for you to use that function instead?

Comment: @Rikard...I'm not sure.  I plan on getting back to this in the future and I can try then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `opts` too. For example:

```
var opts = new Mock<IDataQueryOptions>();
opts.Setup(m => m.ApplyTo(It.IsAny</* Whatever class this takes in */>()))
    .Returns(/* Whatever this needs to return */);
```

Notice mocks act on an interface so you will need to create that too. With a mocked object, you call tell it to return whatever you need to unit test.

Comment: What's IDataQueryOptions?  If you mean IODataQueryOptions, it doesn't exist.  There is no interface for ODataQueryOptions that I'm aware of.

Comment: @BigDaddy I think they are saying you need to create `IDataQueryOptions` (and a wrapper class) to abstract usage of `ODataQueryOptions`.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk...you may be right, but there's gotta be a better way to test this.  BTW, the ODataQueryOptions doesn't seem to be the bottleneck.  It's asserting what it's returning that's the problem for me.