# How to correctly unit test OData v6.0 controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm attempting to unit test out OData controllers, however the APIs changed and previously recommended methods I tried do not work - currently I'm getting

> No non-OData HTTP route registered.

when trying to instantiate ODataQueryOptions to be passed into the Get method of the controller

My current code (based on answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16361875/297606)):

```
       [TestMethod()]
    public void RankingTest()
    {
        var serviceMock = new Mock<IVendorService>();
        serviceMock.SetReturnsDefault<IEnumerable<Vendor>>(new List<Vendor>()
        {
           new Vendor() { id = "1" }
        });

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/odata/Vendor");

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Vendor>("Vendor");
        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        HttpRouteCollection routes = new HttpRouteCollection();
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(routes) { IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always };

        // attempting to register at least some non-OData HTTP route doesn't seem to help
        routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
            );
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", model);
        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
        config.EnsureInitialized();

        request.SetConfiguration(config);
        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(
            model,
            typeof(Vendor),
            new ODataPath(
                new Microsoft.OData.UriParser.EntitySetSegment(
                    model.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("Vendor"))
            )
        );


        var controller = new VendorController(serviceMock.Object);
        controller.Request = request;

        // InvalidOperationException in System.Web.OData on next line:
        // No non-OData HTTP route registered
        var options = new ODataQueryOptions<Vendor>(context, request);

        var response = controller.Get(options) as ViewResult;

    }
```

Thanks for any ideas or pointers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a call to `EnableDependencyInjection` method from the `System.Web.OData.Extensions.HttpConfigurationExtensions` class:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

//1        
config.EnableDependencyInjection();

//2 
config.EnsureInitialized();
```